# Theme CSS won't load in a D8 theme

Tags: theming

I'm creating a new D8 theme and am having trouble making Drupal load the CSS that is a part of my theme. I have disabled cache and am sure I'm getting the up-to-date output.

Here's my **mytheme.info.yml:**

```
name: Mytheme
type: theme
description: 'This is a description.'
core: 8.x

libraries:
  - mytheme/global-styling

libraries-override:
  system/base: false

regions:
  header: Header
  content: Content  # the content region is required
  menu_primary: 'Menu - Primary'
  menu_secondary: 'Menu - Secondary'
  footer: Footer
```

Here's **mytheme.libraries.yml**

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/global.css: {}
```

and this is the top of my **html.html.twig** file:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>{{ head_title }}</title>
   <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
   <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
   <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
   {{ page.head }}
   {{ page.styles }}
   {{ page.scripts }}
</head>
...
```

The content in the YAML files is not tabbed, spaces are used.

I already spent several hours trying to figure out what's wrong and why the global.css is not being linked in the header of the html page, but I have no idea. I'll be gratefull for any help.

EDIT: I found out that my CSS do load when I use this:

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/global-styling') }}
```

but I thought the point of referring to global-styling inside mytheme.info.yml was that I don't have to do that. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Is the name of the theme mytheme or logis?

Comment: mytheme, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am using this in my base theme, and it works:

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      css/YOURCSSFILE.css: {}
```

Comment: No difference. I also added an edit to the bottom of my description of the problem.